# Change of order of quantifiers "every$\text{ }t$" and "almost surely": what difference does it make?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, intuition, quantifiers, almost-everywhere

Given a certain probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ and a random variable $X:t\mapsto X(t)$ defined on it, which is the difference between the following statements:
$$\color{blue}{\text{every }t}\text{ is }\color{red}{\text{almost surely}}\text{ a nondifferentiability point for }X(t)\tag{1}$$
$$\color{red}{\text{almost surely }} \color{blue}{\text{every }t}\text{ is a nondifferentiability point for }X(t)\tag{2}$$
?

---

I would rewrite $(1)$ as:
$$\tag{1.int}\forall t\text{, }\mathbb{P}(t\text{ is a nondifferentiability point for}X(t))=1$$
and $(2)$ as:
$$\tag{2.int}\mathbb{P}(t\text{ is a nondifferentiability point for}X(t), \forall t)=1$$

---

---

First, I don't know whether $(1.\text{int})$ and $(2.\text{int})$ are correct "rewritings" of $(1)$ and $(2)$ (resp.).
 In general, whichever the difference between $(1)$ and $(2)$, which is the gist of such a difference from a mathematical standpoint? I cannot grasp it.

---

---

---

Could you please give an example of a random variable for which $(1)$ holds true, but $(2)$ does NOT hold true? (or viceversa)

Comment: You already know the correct interpretation!

Comment: Good, but I cannot understand what it does mean "practically": could you give me an example of a random variable for which $(1)$ holds true, but $(2)$ does NOT hold true? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: For any fixed $t_0$, note that
the set in (2.int) is a subset of the set in (1.int) at $t=t_0$. So (2.int) implies (1.int) by subadditivity.

Answer (score 5):

On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure let $X_t(\omega)=|t-\omega|$. Then $P(X_t \, \text  {is differentiable at } \, t)=1$ for each $t$ and $P(X_t \, \text  {is differentiable at every point} \, t)=0$.

(2) implies (1) always.

Comment: Why, for $X_t(\omega)=|t-\omega|$, does it hold true that $P(X_t \text{ is differentiable at }t)=1$ for each $t$?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Because $P$ here is the Lebesgue measure and Lebesgue measure of $(0,1) \setminus \{t\}$ is $1$.